# how to change uiimage's nsdata into binary data in order to send to php

Tags: php, objective-c, ios5, uiimage

First I show my related code:

convert UIImage into NSData:

```
 imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
```

Then I wrote the NSMutableRequest:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://136.206.46.10/~katie_xueke/test.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Then I wrote the NSMutableData:

```
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//Image
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name =\"image\";filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type:application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Length: %@\r\n",postLength]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

$$Question is: The NSData seems can't send to the server side and the body part which showed in the console window is like this:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name ="image";filename="2012:03:06 15:06:48"

Content-Type:application/octet-stream



Content-Length: 164692

¬âPNG
```

How to change uiimage's nsdata into binary data in order to send to php??

PS: I tried the     Uint8     method

```
UInt8 *rawData = [imageData bytes];
```

## But it seems that iOS 5 has deprecated it.

On the php side:

```
$uploaddir = './upload/';    
echo "recive a image";    
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);    
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;    

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {    
    echo "/uploads/{$file}";
```

}

I copied it from some other place and I don't know how to show up my POST image on the webpage.

Someone can help me?

Many thanks.

Comment: You did correctly convert the image to data but you are trying to view the binary as a string. That output is part of the PNG header and it stops printing because a null character occurred. To dump data you need to use hex. (`NSLog` an `NSData` object will do a hex dump)

Comment: do you know how to show the image using php?

Comment: `-bytes` is definitely not deprecated. It's the class's primitive! What led you to believe it was?

Comment: If doing stuff manually is becoming too stressful try ASIHTTPRequest: https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request

Comment: But I found out that ASIHTTPRequest can't use on iOS 5….. is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution by myself.

```
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXX"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"uploadedfile" fileName:dateTime mimeType:@"images/png"];
}];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

}];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"response string: %@", operation.responseString); //Lets us know the result including failures
}];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

I used the AFNetworking instead of ASIHttpRequest.

On the php side, my code:

```
<?php

$filename="uploaded";
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

And thank you guys who helped me.

PS:Thanks a lot for this person who actually helped me on this:
http://6foot3foot.com/developer-journal/afnetworking-php